# Purpose of orderBy on collection field?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sql-order-by

I tried to retrieve ordered list of elements from the database. From what I understand, [@orderBy](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/order) annotation should be sufficient.

It is possible to annotate two places:

**field representing collection**

```
@OrderBy
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = Entry.REPORT_PROP)
private List<Entry> elements
```

**getter**

```
@OrderBy
public List<Entry> getElements()
```

**The problem intro**
If both field and getter are annotated, the retrieved list is correctly ordered. However, if only field is annotated, the retrieved list is using database natural ordering.

**The question**
Does annotating only field do anything? And if not, why is it possible to annotate only field?

Comment: Why aren't you using OrderBy("fieldToUseWhenOrdering")? Can you see if it works?

Comment: I had been using it, but it made no difference since I wanted order by primary key, which @OrderBy defaults to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't matter where you put the annotation. Depending on how you annotate, there should be three cases:

```
@OneToMany(...)
private List<Entry> elements;
```

should mean that the list is retrieved without any particular order (your SQL database will probably return them in some ordered form, but according to the standard, it is perfectly legal if it doesn't).

```
@OrderBy
@OneToMany(...)
private List<Entry> elements;
```

should retrieve the entries ordered by primary key, and

```
@OrderBy("fieldname asc")
@OneToMany(...)
private List<Entry> elements;
```

should retrieve the entries ordered by fieldname in ascending order, corresponding to the following JPQL statement:

```
"select e from Entry e ordered by fieldname asc"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the problem is that in my experience it did matter where I put the annotation. Of course, it is possible that I made some mistake. Could you show some reference, for hibernate, which confirms your statement?

Comment: JSR-317 at http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html specifies in section 11.1.38 that the @OrderBy annotation has @Target({METHOD, FIELD}) and thus can be put at either location. The Hibernate docs at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html_single/ don't disagree.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'm still bit fuzzy since in the JSR-317, there are only examples for annotating GETTER methods, but no examples for FIELD annotation.